# Can an SVN external pull down a Git repository's submodules?

Tags: git, svn, github, svn-externals

Since Github allows you to pull Git repositories down as SVN, I've included a Github repository as an external.

- trunk (svn:external https://github.com/Automattic/vip-quickstart base)

... that works great. BUT that repository has its *own* submodules (see https://github.com/Automattic/vip-quickstart/tree/master/puppet/modules) and they aren't being downloaded on `svn update`.

Can an SVN external pull down submodules? If so, how?